# Possible to override toString for SQLDelight generated class?

Tags: kotlin, sqldelight

I'm using SQLDelight to generate models for an app I'm working on. Is there a way to specify a custom toString method for the generated data classes? I realize I could create a subclass and override it but I'd prefer not to do that.

Comment: Hi, Did you get a solution for this?